# Custom Sorting models by distance based on location properties with Ember.js

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I have models with Lat/Long properties and I would like to sort them by distance based on my current location (which I get using html5 geolocation request from google map api v3).

Can I do the sorting using emberjs (knowing its some computing to compare the point with my current location)? What strategy should I use?

The Json structure:

```
point: {
  "id" : 1, 
  "name": "Name", 
  "x": '50.801268', 
  "y": '4.393162'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your models are part of an `ArrayController`.

In that case, you should be able to use:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_sortProperties

This code may help:

http://jsbin.com/ifamox/1/edit

Comment: thanks, that helped a bit but I ended up using computed properties sorting:

https://gist.github.com/borisrorsvort/6188775